# i am getting a memoryOutOfBounds exception while loading my view on the listview

Tags: java, android, media-player

```
    public View getView(int position, View songLay, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //map to song layout
          songLay = songInf.inflate
              (R.layout.song, parent, false);
          //get title and artist views
          TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
          ImageView iv= (ImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          //get song using position
          Song currSong = songs.get(position);
          //get title and artist strings
          songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
          artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());

           //Drawable img=Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getAlbumPath());

              iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart/"+currSong.getAlbumPath()));
             // iv.setImageDrawable(img);
              if(iv.getDrawable()==null)
              {
                  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
              }


          //set position as tag
          songLay.setTag(position);
          return songLay;
    }

}
```

This is the View function I am using to populate the list View for a media player but it is giving a `memoryOutOfBoundsException` and the application forcefully stops.Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you using `songs.size()` value in `getCount()` function of Adapter?

Comment: Not that this is necessarily causing your problem, but you should not be inflating every time `getView` is called. Check if `songLay` is null before inflating.

Comment: i did that but then it just inflates with the first 6 song on repeat..As in there are still the same number of entries but the first 6 entries are only repeated

Comment: Okay no, I think its working. Thank you so much